# Creating Ubuntu Indicator Applet for Java Application

Tags: java, python, swing, ubuntu, gtk

Is there a way to do it with Swing? Or is the best way to write the applet with Python and GTK? If that's the way that I have to do it, how would I launch the indicator and the Java code at the same time? Is it as simple as writing an executable script? Is there a tighter, more seemless way to do it? Pretty new to this platform optimization...

Comment: Indicator for what about 'the application'?  You'll need to add more words before that makes sense to me.

Comment: The applets that Ubuntu has on its menu bar. They are used for the system functions such as the clock, sound, and network, but they can also be tied into somehow by applications. I would like to create a menu using these applets in a similar fashion as the quickstart menu on Windows. I want to click and be able to choose options from the menu.

Comment: Start with a [tag:java-web-start] shortcut.

Comment: How would I use a web-start? It's a desktop application, not a web or serverside client.